# Working with cookie in mvc

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have 2 different urls to login into the application as follows

For Trainee:- http://localhost:56739/trainee/Login/myclientname

For Admin:-   http://localhost:56739/admin/Login/myclientname

I am logging into the application using the below default login implementation

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

What i observed the method `PasswordSignInAsync` is creating the cookie for logged in user.

However my issue is if I logged in using `trainee` url and tries to access the `admin` url then user is directly getting logged in into the admin application without asking for login, because of the cookie. Means the cookie is getting accessed/shared between trainee and admin.

My views are different for `admin/trainee` but they are in same project with below folder structure.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyOhW.png

When i checked in the layout page for below line of code when switching between trainee and admin, this `IsAuthenticated` coming true though the `admin` is still not logged into the application and vice versa.

```
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

I am using identity framework for user authentication.

How can i maintain the separate cookie while switching between `admin/trainee` ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: You should use roles for users: Admin, Trainee. And then put `[Authenticate(Roles = "Admin")]` for admin area controllers and `[Authenticate(Roles="Trainee")]` for trainee controllers

Comment: @trailmax no that is not the case.  I different ui for admin and trainee.. even there layouts,  viewstart are different

Comment: you can still achieve that with roles

Comment: Is this for ASP.NET *OR* ASP.NET Core? The two things are different, but you've used both tags.

Comment: This is asp.net core..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forms authentication cookie is shared throughout an application. Different views mean nothing.

You have two options

1) Separate them into two apps, so cookies are no longer shared automatically.

2) As suggested in the comments assign a role or claim to the administrator accounts, then check that in the authorize attribute or policy.

Comment: These are the only ways available.. what if I write cookie middleware ?

Comment: Sure, feel free, don't forget you need to sign and encrypt and validate. Frankly adding a role to your database is going to be way less effort.

Comment: Yeah.. my application is multitenant application., though I seprate the app or go with the role this issue will occure there also

Comment: Does each tenant get a separate URL? Or do they all share the same URL? Usually we'd expect you to at least put a tenant ID in your identity when you create it, so roles would fit in right there,

Comment: They share the same url, only the client name will get changed, you can see the provided url in question. How can I put a tenant id.. the cookie is automatically created

Comment: Then you're on your own. This isn't how ASP.NET Core cookie auth works. You're going to have to add a tenant ID, which is usually claim, and then use both declarative and imperative claims policies. And that's going to take some research on your part, it is specific to your architecture, your database, your rules, and isn't easy to do.

Comment: Ok so even writing cookie middleware will not work ?? Do you have any examples of using claims ?

Comment: No I don't have examples using claims, that would be down to your database and whatever you are doing to create the cookies

Comment: If I need to use claims, then default login implementation also needs to be changed?

Comment: Which default? Where does this default come from?

Comment: When we create a new mvc app from visual studio templates,  then they have shown login mechanism using Password SignInAsync method, I have used the same

Comment: The default templates are not aimed at muti-tenancy. I assume you mean the individual authentication templates, as there's no Password.SignInAsync(). Those support roles with the default schema.

Comment: Comments to an answer are not the place to have architectural discussions.

Comment: @Rohit Mr. Blowdart gave you several options. You can either write your own cookie middleware (which I advise against, it's not as trivial as it sounds), use claims, or use real multi-tenancy (separate domains, for example). Which of these is correct is up to you and your needs. If you have questions about actually doing one of those things, like "How do I assert a particular controller action asserts on a claim" you can always [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) so long as the question is specific and can be answered clearly.